# How to select records close to one in SQL?

Tags: sql, sorting

I have a single table in database, with a structure like:

```
Id |   Name   |     Money
--------------------------
1  |   Joe    |    34.50
2  |   Jane   |    12.55
3  |   Kate   |    55.21
4  |   George |    9.54
5  |   Hilary |    45.21
6  |   Jacob  |    32.00
7  |   Ginny  |    21.00
```

Now I want to select one specified record (knowing it's `Id`) and 3 others, closest to it (sorting by `Money`).

So it's something like:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY money LIMIT 4;
```

Just with closest (by `Money`) to selected row's money results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort by the absolute difference:

```
SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY ABS(Money - (
    SELECT Money FROM test WHERE Id = 2
)) 
LIMIT 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM test where money>= order by money LIMIT 4;*

Ex: Select * from test where money >=21.00 order by money LIMIT 4;

This would be a simpler solution.